# How to limit dataLabels in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to limit number of datalabel thats showing on the chart. I have no clue how to do that.
The chart it self has many data points, and i want to limit just datalabels for better reading.
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jx5H.png)

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        dht22temp = Highcharts.chart('containerDHT22Temp', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestDataDHT22_Temp
                },
            },
            title: {
                text: 'DHT22 Temperatura'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temp',
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Temp',
                data: [<?php echo join($dataDHT22Temp, ',') ?>],
            }],
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: ['printChart', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF', 'downloadSVG']
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that chart link you posted what you are getting now or what you want it to be?

Answer (score 2):

Check `dataLabels.formatter`:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                     return this.point.index%3 == 0 ? this.y + '°C' : undefined;
                }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
 margin: 10px auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
 font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        This chart shows how data labels can be added to the data series. This
        can increase readability and comprehension for small datasets.
    </p>
</figure>
```